# Time out issue with CRM Online service object

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am working on MS D CRM Online V8.0. I have written a Windows Service that bulk updates records for an entity (500 record each time). I am facing a time out issue and authentication failure with the service object. We have set the time out to 10 mins.

Algorithm:

1. Fetch 500 Records for Entity
2. Update the same records. Set Status = In progress
3. Do the Process
4. Create the service object again
5. Update the records. Set Status = Complete.

I get the below exception

> 2018-03-05 09:36:04,267 [1] DEBUG -
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection
>   was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The
>   connection was closed unexpectedly.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Please show your code setting up the connection and calling the service. We can’t you without code to work from.

Comment: 2018-03-05 09:36:04,267 [1] DEBUG - System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Sorry. I cant share the code. However, i get the above exception.